# Error in Select Case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

Could somebody please tell me what they can see that is the problem in the code below?

```
--Query for DC Allocated Stock - Qty & Values
-------------------------------------------

    Declare @Brand varchar(50),
        @Div varchar(50),
        @Dept varchar(50),
        @Store varchar(50),
        @StyleOrSKU varchar(50)


    Set @Brand = 'TestProduct' --Test criteria
    set @Div = ''
    Set @Dept = ''
    set @Store = ''
    set @StyleOrSKU = ''
```

First query, table Qry_1_DCSOH - to return the stock quantity on hand

```
SELECT Brand, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Brand = @Brand THEN sum(AllocStockQty)
         WHEN Division = @Div THEN sum(AllocStockQty)
         WHEN Department = @Dept THEN sum(AllocStockQty)
         WHEN Store = @Store THEN sum(AllocStockQty)
         WHEN StyleOrSKU = @StyleOrSKU THEN sum(AllocStockQty)
         ELSE 'NoMatch' 
      END as [Allocated Stock Qty]
FROM Qry_2_DCAllocStock 
GROUP BY Brand, Division, Department, Store, StyleOrSKU
```

The error I get is Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 20
Error converting data type varchar to float.

But I am really not sure where the problem is - please assist.

Comment: What kind of language is that? Can you adjust the tagging of your question?

Comment: I'm guessing this is SQL. It would be helpful for you to specify which is line 20, but the error message is pretty sure that you're trying to get a varchar datatype to equate to a float somewhere.

Comment: Apologies folks - this is SQL

Comment: formatting, grammar

Answer (score 0):

You have varchar(50) types.. and it seems the **from clause is returning some numeric values**.

Cast the When clauses to var char or use the returned types on the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that you are trying to force a no numeric value with the else option for a computed expression that has already float values.
It can be corrected like this:

```
SELECT Brand, 
   CASE 
     WHEN Brand = @Brand THEN sum(AllocStockQty)
     WHEN Division = @Div THEN sum(AllocStockQty)
     WHEN Department = @Dept THEN sum(AllocStockQty)
     WHEN Store = @Store THEN sum(AllocStockQty)
     WHEN StyleOrSKU = @StyleOrSKU THEN sum(AllocStockQty)
     ELSE 0 
  END as [Allocated Stock Qty]
FROM Qry_2_DCAllocStock 
GROUP BY Brand, Division, Department, Store, StyleOrSKU
```

Comment: Thanks all for your help - sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing data types in your `CASE`.

The [return type of `CASE` is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-types):

> ... the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

The [highest precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) type is `float` in your example.

Either change the type of your else result or convert the sum results to some char type.